# Visual C++ 2010: Including boost in several projects in a solution?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, configuration, dry, propertysheet

I'm using the [boost library](http://www.boost.org/) in several projects in my Visual C++ 2010 solution.  What I'm currently doing is modifying each project's properties by setting:

1. Properties->Configuration Properties->C/C++->General->Additional Include Directories to include the boost directory `C:\boost\boost_1_47`
2. Properties->Configuration Properties->Linker->General->Additional Library Directories to include the boost lib directory `C:\boost\boost_1_47\lib`

Now that I'm upgrading my boost version to 1.51 I realize I'm violating DRY by specifying this information more than once (i.e., once for each project).  I want to define the boost info in a single place.

After researching it seems like [Property Sheets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a4xbdz1e%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) are a good solution.  I've read about property sheet inheritance but I don't see how that's useful because it seems that if you want to add a project-specific include directory then you will have to set the Additional Include Directories in the properties for that specific project which will then override the inherited property sheet which defines the boost include directory.  If I am wrong about this please correct me.

So my next thought is to create a single property sheet called GlobalMacros.prop and define a user macro something like `$(BoostDir)` and then add this property sheet to each project.  Then I can use the macro in each project's properties when I'm defining include directories and library directories.  However, when creating a macro there is an option "set this macro as an environment variable in the build environment" and I am not sure what that does or if I should set it.

Overall I want to know what is the best way to reduce repeated configuration definitions for common settings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm actually the developer that originally implemented property sheets in Visual C++ back in VS 2005 (although I'm not responsible for the mess that is the VC++ project properties dialog).  Caveat: I stopped working on VC++ after 2005, so below may not be entirely accurate for your version.

In the Property Manager, you should be able to multiselect all of your project configurations in all projects and add a new property sheet.  This will automatically inherit those project configurations from the same property sheet.  In that property sheet, set the boost include and library directories directly or use a macro for **BoostVersion** and **BoostDir** and use those macros in the property sheet's properties.

Provided that the project configurations have "inherit from parent or project defaults" checked (this controls inserting $(Inherit) vs $(NoInherit) in 2005/2008 and %(<propertyname>) in 2010/2012) for those properties, you should see any project-specific properties set in the project configurations prepended, by default, to the values in the property sheet.

You can confirm this by going to a project and checking the compiler's "Command Line" tab to see if the switches are what you expect.

Edit: note that there are two types of properties in VC++: "single-value" and "multi-value".  An example of a single-value property is the compiler's warning level.  The value on the command line for a single-value property comes from the first place in the property inheritance chain that specifies it, starting with the project configuration, then the property sheets, then the built-in default in the project system.  An example of a multi-value property is the compiler's include directories.  Multi-value properties get concatenated with their parent property sheets unless $(NoInherit) is specified (2005/2008) or %(<propertyname>) is not specified (2010/2012).  Thus, by default, you should see the boost paths showing up in your project settings provided they have intentionally not inherited the property from the property sheet.

Comment: Thanks, good tip about multi-select to add a property sheet to all projects.  Also thanks for the clarification on the single vs multi-value property types I think that's the info I need.  Regarding inheritance, reading this blog post [Sharing project properties](http://manski.net/2012/01/11/sharing-project-properties-in-visual-c/#property-sheet-order) suggests that the properties are inherited from the "bottom up" in the property manager.  My first instinct is that I'd want my "global" property sheet to be higher in the inheritance hierarchy.  But I guess you're saying that's not necessary?

Comment: Also do you have any guidance for this particular boost use-case on whether it's better to use macros or let the properties be inherited?

Comment: It depends on how you view it, I guess.  In the Property Manager, a property sheet inherits the settings from the property sheet below it.  However, command line evaluation goes from project configuration on down in that model.  That is, if the property sheet is "higher" in the Property Manager (i.e. closet to the project configuration), its properties are used before the ones below it.  My suggestion to you is to create a single property sheet with a macro called BoostDir set to C:\boost\boost_1_47\; then use $(BoostDir)lib and $(BoostDir) in the same property sheet for lib/inc dirs.

Comment: And have that property sheet sit below the project configuration in the Property Manager.  That should do the trick for you.

Comment: Came to a similar conclusion.  Seems like macros are a little more flexible and a little more explicit also.